# drf-spectacular error - Function Based Views - unable to guess serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, documentation, openapi, drf-spectacular

I'm getting the following error when trying to generate the schema:
" Error [get_token]: unable to guess serializer. This is graceful fallback handling for APIViews. Consider using GenericAPIView as view base class, if view is under your control. Either way you may want to add a serializer_class (or method)"

I'm using a function based view, snippet below:

```
from .serializers.auth import GetTokenSerializer

@api_view(["POST"])
@authentication_classes([UserTypeBasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@check_request(GetTokenSerializer)
@extend_schema(
    request=GetTokenSerializer,
    responses=None
)
def get_token(request: Request) -> Response:
...
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer from the wonderful creator of drf-spectacular. Solve is here:
https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/969

Basically, you should put the @extend_schema decorator on top, especially over  @api_view